# Android Studio: XML Layout does not appear

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

**Android Developers,**
I have a problem when I use **Android Studio**, XML layout does not shown in design mode and I get message **" No render target selected"**

Does anyone face this problem before and what is the solution for this ?

Comment: From the top menu option of `display` tab in android studio select any other version which is provided near `theme` and other options

Comment: There is no versions, how to add them ?

Comment: choose another target ..It will work..

Comment: choose a lower target.

Answer (score 0):

**Checkout This ScreenShot Here You Can Clearly See that list of devices Which You Can Choose To Render**

[image: Rendering Target Selection]